# Strange JavaScript behaviour on mobile Safari iOS 6

Tags: javascript, math, mobile-safari, ios6

I ran into a very very very strange JS issue that is reproducing only on Mobile Safari browser on iOS 6. 
The issue is in a function that formats a given value to a price, by stripping down the number to 2 decimals and adds the currency in front of the number. Here are the functions. I will explain later on how to reproduce the bug.

```
formatCurrency = function(value, currency, fixedPrecision, colourize, blankIfZero) {
    var text;

    if (blankIfZero && (Math.abs(value) < 0.01 || value === undefined)) {
         return "";
    }

    if (fixedPrecision) {
        text = currency + Math.abs(value).toFixed(2);
    } else {
        text = currency + roundTo2Decimals(Math.abs(value));
    }

    if (value < 0) {
        text = "-" + text;
    }

    if (colourize) {
        var colorClass = (value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
        text = "<span class='" + colorClass + "'>" + text + "</span>";
    }

    return text;
};

roundTo2Decimals = function(value) {
    var sign = value < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    return Math.round(Math.abs(value) * 100.0)/100.0 * sign;    
};
```

If I run the the formatCurrency  function over and over again (within a setInterval for example) with the same value (lets say value=1; and currency="GBP") you will notice the once every 800-1000 iterations the value return by the function contains a negative amount: GBP-1 instead of GBP1. This issue is very annoying i I did not found any issue within the JS functions.

I manage to fix the issue ... but I'm curious what is the issue with this implementation. [Edit: I fixed the issue by removing the "-" character from the "roundTo2Decimals(Math.abs(value))". But the "-" char should never appear in the first place. So the fix was actually a workaround.]

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you found the solution/workaround, please, post it as an answer so others can benefit from it.

Comment: For anyone else experiencing this bug, I believe I have a reproducible case of it, if not a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139746/ios-javascript-engine-parsefloat1-returns-negative-number-when-math-abs-is-use

Comment: Note that blankIfZero bypasses the rounding code for small values resulting in inconsistent results. That is 0.009 will return the empty string "0.01" while 1.009 will return "1.01". This check should be < 0.005

Answer (score -1):

I guess;

text = "-" + String(text);

is the issue.

Me too have been surfing around a lot for iOS6 related bugs in Safari. It seems the JS should be lot more cleaner if we want it to execute smooth!

Comment: Please have in mind that when the issue is occurring the "-" sign is after the currency code (GBP-10), not  in front of the currency code (-GBP10). "text = "-" + String(text);" will place the "-" sign in front of the currency.