# iOS Javascript engine parseFloat(1) returns negative number

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

This code will make the bug appear:

```
function causeBug(d) {
  var k;
  var n = parseFloat(1);
  var c = Math.abs(d);
  if (n < 0) {
    k = '-';
  } else {
    k = '+';
  }
  return k + n; 
}

$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2000; ++i) {
      $('body').append(i + ': ' + causeBug(2) + '<br>');
  }
});
```

It is visible in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H2SEN/16/ (view in Mobile Safari, scroll down and at some point you will see parseFloat(1) < 0). The negative has been spotted anywhere from the 73rd iteration to over 1500.

Note some of the seemingly unnecessary code like for example the unused parameter `d` and the unused variable `var c = Math.abs(d);` are actually necessary for the error to occur. This is also true for the usage of n in the return statement, and the parseFloat call (although parseInt also causes it).

Bug only reproduced on real iPhone 4s (7.0.6) and two iPod Touch (7.1 beta). Not in iPads or iOS Simulator, or any desktop browser. The bug will not occur if you have remote debugging enabled and a Safari console open on your computer.

I am fairly confident this is the exact cause for this unanswered question: [Strange JavaScript behaviour on mobile Safari iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821635/strange-javascript-behaviour-on-mobile-safari-ios-6)

Any insight into potential causes of this bug would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, we are not supposed to pass an Int to this function -> "The parseFloat() function parses a string argument and returns a floating point number." In Java, the toString() function should be automatically called because the input parameter type is String but in Javascript... there is no guaranty that Safari mobile does a proper toString() with a proper memory allocation at each call. They even might use some "optimised" coding trick to make it fast to execute. You might have found a nice bug to report to the mobile safari team.

Comment: This executes as expected in mobile Safari on iPhone 5S 8.0.1

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if the same issue occurs if the `Math.abs(d)` is replaced with any other function call, such as `d.split(" ");`.  And if so, if it still occurs if a user-defined function is called instead (like `myCustomAbs(d)`).  It could be you've stumbled across a transient error when context-switching to/from a native function implementation.

Comment: You can see in @startswithaj's answer below, replacing with myCustomAbs function does in fact work around this issue (and is what we've had to do). Apple Bug ID is 16209709 apparently.

Answer (score 4):

JIT issue perhaps? I found the implementation of Math.abs in the JavascriptCore source which I'm guessing is different from Nitro (ios js engine) or is perhaps marked as JIT executable.

```
Value MathFuncImp::call(ExecState *exec, Object &/*thisObj*/, const List &args)
{
  double arg = args[0].toNumber(exec);
  double arg2 = args[1].toNumber(exec);
  double result;

  switch (id) {
  case MathObjectImp::Abs:
    result = ( arg < 0 || arg == -0) ? (-arg) : arg;
    break;
```

This can be implemented directly in javascript. So you can replace your Math.abs calls with

```
result = ( arg < 0 || arg == -0) ? (-arg) : arg;
```

This will resolve the issue and be cross browser compatible.

Submitted Apple Bug: 16209709

Does anyone know how this kind of bug occurs or a better way to describe it?

Bit Flip? Memory Collision? Overflow of some sort?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you should use it in standard.
for `parseInt`, it is better to pass second parameter like:
`parseInt(1, 10)`. Or in some IOS system, it will give you wrong answers.

For example, `parseInt(8)` will be traded as octal in IOS (it is weird..).

Comment: That's very true for `parseInt()`.  However, `parseFloat()` does not accept a second paramter for the radix.

Comment: @aroth sorry i confused that, i have reedited my answer.